# How to set manually opened browser as Selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium

I am working on automating a web application.

I have many pages like login page etc. and I have many tabs. Each tab will open different page, for example, if I want to open page3, I have to go through page1 first then page2.

Here my problem is If I want to test some functionality on page3, then I have to go through all pages. It is taking so much time to test single functionality I need to spend so much time.

Is there any way I can set already opened browser as Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

This is the most starred feature request on Selenium as of now (February 2013, current Selenium 2.30.0). It's also one of the oldest.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18

There has been some work on Firefox for this, but it's undocumented, *very* experimental and no changes have been seen on it for quite a while. For more information, look at the linked feature request.

Front-end automation is hard, Selenium can only do what a normal user could do. The best you can do is to run the tests in parallel on many remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

No... It is not possible....

In order to reduce the manual execution, we are moving towards automation.

Inbetween you cannot automate.